# Displaying "N elements hidden" when hiding consequtive DOM elements

Tags: javascript, css

Given some elements (unknown number), out of which some elements should be hidden:

```
<div id="root">
  <div>              1</div>
  <div class="hide"> 2</div>
  <div class="hide"> 3</div>
  <div class="hide"> 4</div>
  <div>              5</div>
  <div>              6</div>
  <div class="hide"> 7</div>
  <div>              8</div>
  <div class="hide"> 9</div>
  <div class="hide"> 10</div>
</div>
```

It is easy to hide the elements with class `hide` with CSS (`.hide { display: none; }`. However, what I want to do is to replace each range of hideable elements with a replacement element, e.g. `<div>Some elements were hidden</div>`, or even better `<div>N elements hidden</div>` where `N` is the number of elements in that range of hidden elements (3, 1, and 2 for the three ranges in the example). This means that the final output would look like:

1, 3 Elements hidden, 5, 6, 1 Element hidden, 8, 2 Elements hidden

First: Is this possible to achieve with only CSS? I cannot think of any way, but there might be someone more creative with selectors than me :)

If this cannot be solved with only CSS, is there a way to achieve this only by adding classes in javascript + `::before`/`::after` psuedo-elements? I.e. without inserting any elements into the "actual" DOM?

Comment: You're almost definitely going to have to use JavaScript here, and unfortunately JS has no ability to modify/create/remove `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: Side-note: I notice this question was voted for closure because it doesn't include a snippet, but the very first sentence of that closure rule states *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") ... "* - This question is **not** seeking debugging help. It is asking if something is possible and for implementation advice. What's the accepted procedure here?

Comment: @Vidar You could do this `css` hack https://jsfiddle.net/02zzp6ae/ and if you need to display hidden elements count you must do some `javascript`. As you say you do not want to add an additional element, you can simply change the contents of your element instead of hiding it.

Comment: @Santi: You can use counter-increment to do this without Javascript. I would still use JS for this kind of stuff, but it does not mean it is needed. See my reply below :)

Comment: @George You can use counter-increment to add the exact number without JS. The only drawback is that you cannot use display:none; but you can replace that for other similar approaches like reducing font, size, visbility, etc...

Comment: @AZee You can use counter-increment to add the exact number without Javascript. See my answer below :)

Comment: @fvbuendia Thank you. I really like your answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the good suggestions, it helped push me in the right direction. I ended up marking certain elements with a data attribute (`data-n-hidden-before` + `data-n-hidden-after`) and the `content: attr(data-n-hidden-before) " element(s) hidden";` CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use Javascript for this. However, if you really want to stick to only CSS you can accomplish it with a few tricks:

```
.hide {
 counter-increment: hiddenElements;
 visibility: hidden;
 font-size: 0px; 
}
```

`counter-increment: hiddenElements;` will autoincrease the value every hidden element. The catch is that this does not work with display: none; Hence, I am using `visibility: hidden;` and  `font-size: 0px;`as a workaround to accomplish the same or close enough.

```
.hide + div:not(.hide):before {
  content: counter(hiddenElements) " element(s) hidden \A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

This piece is writing the number of elements hidden when it encounters a hidden element followed by not hidden element. This means that there should always be a last (empty?) `<div></div>` to ensure this fires.

```
.hide + div:not(.hide) + div {
  counter-reset: hiddenElements;
}
```

This resets the counter on the div after writing the number of elements.

You can see a demo below.

```css
.hide {
 counter-increment: hiddenElements;
 visibility: hidden;
 font-size: 0px; 
}

.hide + div:not(.hide):before {
  content: counter(hiddenElements) " element(s) hidden \A";
  white-space: pre;
}

.hide + div:not(.hide) + div {
  counter-reset: hiddenElements;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div>              1</div>
  <div class="hide"> 2</div>
  <div class="hide"> 3</div>
  <div class="hide"> 4</div>
  <div>              5</div>
  <div>              6</div>
  <div class="hide"> 7</div>
  <div>              8</div>
  <div class="hide"> 9</div>
  <div class="hide"> 10</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

As you see, it works, but it has many small "concerns". I would really advocate for a JS approach here. Do not hesitate to open a question with the Javascript tag and I am happy to assist you there too.

Comment: TIL about counters :)

Comment: I ended up using something with JS, but this answer still answers it the best. The solution I ended with was along the lines of this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kqzmvsLy/2/

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't tag the question with jQuery, but here's a way to do it if you're open to using it:

```js
$('#root div').each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('hide')) {
    var count = $(this).nextUntil(':not(.hide)').addBack().length;
    $(this).html( count + ' elements hidden')
    $(this).next('.hide').hide()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div> 1</div>
  <div class="hide"> 2</div>
  <div class="hide"> 3</div>
  <div class="hide"> 4</div>
  <div> 5</div>
  <div> 6</div>
  <div class="hide"> 7</div>
  <div> 8</div>
  <div class="hide"> 9</div>
  <div class="hide"> 10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

How about using `css counter`?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

```
#root {
  counter-reset: section;
}

#root > div.hide {
  counter-increment: section;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#root > .hide + div:not(.hide):before {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: counter(section) " element hidden";
}

#root > .hide + div:not(.hide) + div {
  counter-reset: section;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amoshydra/wkuyj5kc/5/

---

Opps, didn't read the question clearly..
I will leave my old answer here..

---

How do you like this hack?

```
.hide {
  transform: scale(0.0001);
  line-height: 80%;
}

.hide:before {
  content: 'This is hidden';
  transform: scale(10000);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/amoshydra/wkuyj5kc/

Comment: I believe OP was aware this was a viable option, the trouble was involving the idea of a "range", where adjacent hidden items are grouped.

Comment: Your solution does not work properly. If you remove:   <div> 11</div> it will not count the last group of empty elements. That's why my reply had the last <div> to ensure you always count ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's right. Actually I forked the code written by AZee to create the element grouping technique, so it isn't a complete hack.. And I was quite excited when I learn about counter-increment at that time.. haha